# Increment Value On Basis of Count with Button Click

Tags: excel, vba

I want the Value should be Auto Printed Number of Times When Count is Given

[image: My Image 1]

If you see my image there is Count and Value as some Data like 'DEMO'
When I enter count like 5 then the Data in Value = Demo should be printed that many times as Count is mentioned Under Column => H

Like Below Output Image 
[image: My Image 2]
I can Drag the cell upto particular Count... this may work for me 
But when the count is 5 or 10 ... what if the Count is 100 or 200 or more 
We have to drag the cell upto 100 count and so on

i want to auto increment without Dragging the cell upto the Particular count

I have tried this one But not Working ... Suggest me How do i achieve this

```
Sub Increment()

    Dim startValue
    startValue = Cells(15, 5).Value

    For i = 1 To 10 Step 1
        Cells(i, 5).Value = startValue
        startValue = startValue + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

here is the Google Drive file link would you be able to illustrate on this and share https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D5GblPrcnaGQqKUwhj5YIthhgQxkHldl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this have to be VBA? You could do this with a formula.  Going off the provided image, in cell H3 and copied down: `=IF(AND($C$3>0,$F$3<>"",$C$3>=ROW(H1)),$F$3,"")`

Comment: @tigeravatar my friend.. Know that i want in this method only because i want to avoid Dragging the Cell Down upto Particular Count what if the Count is 300 then I have to Drag it up to 300 count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this must be VBA, then this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim sValue As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rDest = ws.Range("H3")

    With ws.Range(rDest, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, rDest.Column).End(xlUp))
        If .Row >= rDest.Row Then .ClearContents    'Clear previous results (if any)
    End With

    lCount = Val(ws.Range("C3").Value)
    sValue = ws.Range("F3").Value

    If lCount > 0 Then rDest.Resize(lCount) = sValue

End Sub
```

Comment: could you explain where you are passing the count value and Data Demo

Comment: @zack count value is assigned to the `lCount` variable and is used in the `.Resize` method.  The Data Demo is assigned to the `sValue` variable.

Comment: thanks for the Help bro @tigeravatar => how do i follow you if i have any issue regarding vba => can you share yourself so that i can get connected to you with socially , facebook or twitter or or any